# US citizen traveling with Peruvian passport

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, us-citizens, dual-nationality, peru

I'm an American citizen. I was born in the US, however I came to visit Ecuador on an emergency basis using my Peruvian passport. I lost my US passport and had no time to get one before coming to Ecuador. Can I fly back to the US with my Peruvian passport only or will I be denied entry? I have my US drivers license, and SS card on me. I don't have a visa since I am a citizen and resident in the US.

Answer (score 31):

A US citizen cannot be denied entry to the USA, although you can expect to be held at the border for sometime while your citizenship is verified.

None of that will matter, because no airline will allow you to board a flight to the US with only a Peruvian passport if you don't have a visa.

You should go to the US embassy in Quito who will be able to issue an emergency travel document that will allow you to get home.

Comment: Specifically, the driver's license and social security card don't prove citizenship.

Comment: If she has time to wait for one, she can also get a full 10-year passport at the US  embassy.  These services [also appear to be available at the US consulate general in Guayaquil](https://ec.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/).

Comment: @DavidRicherby Some drivers licenses (so called "Enhanced Drivers Licenses") do prove citizenship - however they are still not considered sufficient/valid for international travel by air.

Comment: Peruvians are visa-free for Mexico, so the OP _might_ go there and try the land border. But the U.S. consulate in Ecuador is probably a better first plan.

Comment: @HenningMakholm That may just as well make it worse though, if citizenship can't be verified at the land border. They aren't exactly friendly at most landborder crossings there.

Comment: @Mast the Peruvian passport will reflect a US place of birth.  With that and whatever database lookups they have available, it should be possible for the officers to establish that Andrea is a US citizen.  In any event, it's not clear to me how the situation would be worse if they don't accept the claim of US citizenship.

Comment: @phoog: Because then you're stuck in Mexico at the border with no obvious route to either Ecuador or the US.

Comment: @phoog thats not always true. I'm a dual citizen and both my passports show different birth places. (both in locations are in the issuing country).

Comment: @Philippe how is that possible?

Comment: @Kevin how is that worse than being stuck in Ecuador with no obvious route to the US?  Also, there are far more US consulates in Mexico than in Ecuador. If it proved impossible to get past CBP, the obvious response would be to go to the nearest consulate and get a passport.

Comment: @phoog: I imagine that OP has one of a house, family, or other ties to Ecuador, because they traveled there on "an emergency basis." They likely have none of those things in Mexico, so if they get stuck outside the US for a protracted period, Ecuador might be preferable to Mexico.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I think that's the best way to find yourself stuck in some refugee internment camp for a couple of months while they process your request of entry. Going to an embassy seems much more sensible.

Comment: @phoog in some circumstances a passport will use city of nationalization as birthplace for people who were born in another country, favoring the use of a domestic city. In my case my passport lists my mothers birth pace instead of mine since I inherited my citizenship through her even though I was born abroad.